# How to join documents after a pipeline stage in mongo aggregation framwork

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So lets say after the first stage of aggregation I have grouped all the documents by the center so i have something like this:

```
{
center:"A",
gender:"Male",
count:50
}
{
center:"A",
gender:"Female",
count:20
}
```

I want to join these two documents such that the final document looks something like

```
{
center:A,
Male:50,
Female:20
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the example documents and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Provide your original schema,  it may possible to get in single step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce another **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step where you group the incoming documents stream by the center field, introduce new fields within the group that use the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** operator. The **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** operation will be determined by a condition using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator which evaluates the gender expression, and depending on the result, and returns the previous count based on the evaluated logic.

Consider the following pipeline continuation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /* previous pipeline(s) here ... */
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$center",
            "Male": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$gender", "Male" ] }, "$count", 0 ]
                }
            },
            "Female": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$gender", "Female" ] }, "$count", 0 ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "center": "$_id", "Male": 1, "Female": 1
        }
    }
])
```